# How can I extract when a select condition is met in a do loop the value of the iterator?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I use the following code to find out the  number of consecutive prime numbers using a formula $n^2+n+i$ found out by Euler (starting from n=0):

```
Nbs = {};
Do[Nbs = Union[Nbs, 
Select[Range[5000], (PrimeQ[#^2 + # + i] == False &), 1]], {i, 1, 
5000}];
Nbs
```

How can I also get in the output list the value of the `Do` iterator where $i$ is corresponding to each number of consecutive primes?

I would like to get something like that:

```
({1,2},...,{40,41}}
```

Comment: Look up `Reap` and `Sow`

Comment: I don't think your question can be done ... without adding an `If` and `Sow` to your `Select` condition which is ugly beyond reason. Do you care about do this kind of filtering, or is your question specifically about using Select?

Comment: Also you might want to be careful about using capital letters for variables when asking questions ... agitates the style police ...

Comment: @Gabriel A solution was found by Kevin without using Reap and Sow that I do not know how to use here.The Select has to be of the form [list,crit, 1] because I need to get only the first element of the list that satisfies the criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but I believe you want either Nbs2 or Nbs3 (same data, sorted differently) in this code:

```
Nbs = {};
Do[AppendTo[Nbs, 
   Append[Select[Range[5000], (PrimeQ[#^2 + # + i] == False &), 1], 
    i]], {i, 1, 5000}];
Nbs2 = DeleteDuplicates[Nbs, (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]]) &];
Nbs3 = Sort[Nbs2];
```

Where `Nbs2`:

```
{{4, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {10, 11}, {16, 17}, {40, 41}, {3, 65}, {6, 77},
 {12, 221}, {5, 347}, {7, 437}}
```

and `Nbs3`:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 65}, {4, 1}, {5, 347}, {6, 77}, {7, 437},
 {10, 11}, {12, 221}, {16, 17}, {40, 41}}
```

`Nbs` holds the whole data since I am not using `Union` there anymore so that I can keep the iterator as you needed.

Comment: Yes it is indeed a solution at the expense of keeping all data with your use of AppendTo. It avoids the pitfall I went into by using Union , thus eliminating all duplicates straight away.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

My previous answer related to the title of the question and was directed to "reaping" or "catching" first cases of a condition being met from a loop.

The Euler formula, as I now understand, was a method for generating consecutive prime numbers :  $n^2+n+k$, where $k$ is prime and $n$ ranges from 0 to $k-2$. With all due respect this does not appear consistent with the aim of the code. A relevant reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Consecutive_primes).

The following relates to the use of Euler formula to generate consecutive primes:

```
f[u_?PrimeQ] := Module[{s = {}, j = 0},
  While[PrimeQ[j^2 + j + u] && j <= u - 2, AppendTo[s, j^2 + j + u]; 
   j++]; {u, Length@s, s}]
f[u_] := Sequence[];
```

Then:

```
Grid[Prepend[
  f /@ Range[100], {"k", "number of consecutive primes", "Primes"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

yields:

[image]

Further, if the intention is just to explore the effect of any the original code, miscounts as if i is composite the corresponding value j will be 1 greater than the count of consecutive primes, eg i=77-> 79, 83, 89, 97, 107}, i.e. 5 primes not 6 as listed in the OP code (the value for n=6 being 119=7 x 17). My original answer listed all 5000 "answers" (in compact form) based on merely answering the title of the question.

If the purpose is to explore i composite or prime:

```
g[u_?PrimeQ] := Module[{set = {}, j = 0},
  While[PrimeQ[j^2 + j + u] && j <= u - 2, AppendTo[set, j^2 + j + u];
    j++];
  {u, Length@set, set}]
g[u_] := Module[{set = {}, j = 1},
  While[PrimeQ[j^2 + j + u] && j <= u - 2, AppendTo[set, j^2 + j + u];
    j++];
  {u, Length@set, set}]
```

I note that up to 100000, the case i=41 yields the longest number of consecutive primes:

```
prim = g /@ Range[100000];
mx = Max[prim[[All, 2]]];
Cases[prim, {_, mx, _}]
```

yields:

> {41, 40, {41, 43, 47, 53, 61, 71, 83, 97, 113, 131, 151, 173, 197,
>   223, 251, 281, 313, 347, 383, 421, 461, 503, 547, 593, 641, 691,
>   743, 797, 853, 911, 971, 1033, 1097, 1163, 1231, 1301, 1373, 1447,
>   1523, 1601}}}

Comment: Your solution is OK for some value of i but not all of them (see solution given above). I think the problem lies in the fact that you do not catch the cases when n= 0  (it is implicit in the way the Select is coded in my question)